# Nodejs - not sure how to await a database query within a function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm new to nodejs and struggling to get a good handle on the async/await functionality. I've read a bunch of other SE post and many blogs but can't seem to get the right combination of code to achieve the intended program flow.

The general idea of my program is to call the startNextPick() function, which then calls getLeagueFromDraftPicks(). Inside this function is a query which needs to be "waited" on to complete but I'm not sure of the right/simple way to do this. Currently, it is no waiting which is causing the function to return an "undefined" result. What is the right/simple way to have the query response waited on in this context?

```
startNextPick();

async function startNextPick(pickId) {
  console.log('A-- starting next pick');

  var leagueId = await getLeagueFromDraftPick(pickId);

  console.log('B-- leagueId from getLeagueFromDraftPick: '+leagueId);

  leagueId = Number(leagueId);
  if (leagueId > 0) {
    //.... do other stuff here
  } else {
    console.log('Error with finding league based on draft pick');
  }
}

async function getLeagueFromDraftPick(pickId) {
  pickId = Number(pickId);
  var leagueId;
  console.log('1 pickId: '+pickId);
  if (pickId  <= 0) {
    return false;
  }

  // Get LeagueID from draft based on pickId
  // *** Need to "await" this query "
  connection.query('select LEAGUE_ID from DRAFT where ID=? limit 1',
                  [pickId],
                  function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    } else {
      leagueId = results[0].LEAGUE_ID;

      console.log('2--  pickId: '+pickId);
      console.log('3--  leagueId: '+leagueId);

      return leagueId;
    }
  });
  console.log('4--  leagueId: '+leagueId);
  return leagueId;
}
```

Using the console.log to trace the timing and flow of the code, it's clear the query needs to be waited on as the return value for the getLeagueFromDraftPick() is showing undefined yet the results of the query eventually show correctly.

```
Console.log output
****starting next pick****
A-- starting next pick
1 pickId: 19002
4--  leagueId: undefined
B-- leagueId from getLeagueFromDraftPick: undefined
Error with finding league based on draft pick
2--  pickId: 19002
3--  leagueId: 52
```

** Solution **
Using @cyberwombat answer with some modifications I was able to get it working. Below is the working code:

```
async function startNextPick(pickId) {
  console.log('A-- starting next pick');

  var leagueId = await getLeagueFromDraftPick(pickId);

  console.log('B-- leagueId from getLeagueFromDraftPick: '+leagueId);
}


async function getLeagueFromDraftPick(pickId) {
  pickId = Number(pickId);
  console.log('1 pickId: '+pickId);
  if (pickId  <= 0) {
    return false;
  }

  // Get LeagueID from draft based on pickId
  // *** Need to "await" this query "
  const leagueId = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject)  {
    connection.query('select LEAGUE_ID from DRAFT where ID=? limit 1',
                    [pickId],
                    function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      } else {
        if (results[0]) {
          console.log('2--  pickId: '+pickId);
          console.log('3--  leagueId: '+results[0].LEAGUE_ID);

          resolve(results[0].LEAGUE_ID);
        } else {
          resolve(0);        }
      }
    });
  });
  console.log('4--  leagueId: '+leagueId);
  return leagueId;
}


Console output:
****starting next pick****
A-- starting next pick
1 pickId: 19031
2--  pickId: 19031
3--  leagueId: 52
4--  leagueId: 52
B-- leagueId from getLeagueFromDraftPick: 52
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection bit uses a callback. To make that work nicely with your async/await you can wrap it in a promise (you can also look to see if that db library has a promisified/async version). Ideally you want to wrap this in a try/catch block to deal with error but that's a diff story. Here's the code to return the `1eagueId` async.

```
async function getLeagueFromDraftPick(pickId) {
  pickId = Number(pickId);
  var leagueId;
  console.log('1 pickId: '+pickId);
  if (pickId  <= 0) {
    return false;
  }


  const leagueId = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject)  {
    // Get LeagueID from draft based on pickId
    // *** Need to "await" this query "
    connection.query('select LEAGUE_ID from DRAFT where ID=? limit 1',
                  [pickId],
                  function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error)

      } else {
        leagueId = results[0].LEAGUE_ID;

        console.log('2--  pickId: '+pickId);
        console.log('3--  leagueId: '+leagueId);

        resolve(leagueId)
      }
    });
  })

  console.log('4--  leagueId: '+leagueId);
  return leagueId;
}
```

Simplified runnable example:

```js
// Create our async function
async function getLeagueFromDraftPick() {
  console.log('1')
  // We can use the new Promise to wrap old style callbacks - not shown here
  const leagueId = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('2')
    // Fake some delay - i.e. pretend w are doing some http request
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('foo')
     }, 1000);
  })
  console.log('3')
  return leagueId
}

// This weird parenthesis setup is just a trick to run async functions from the console
(async () => {
  const leagueId = await getLeagueFromDraftPick()
  console.log(leagueId)
})()
```

Comment: I posted the final solution above after fixing a few issues in your answer like the duplicate use of leagueId variable. Thanks

Comment: One side question... while this is now working, why does the console log show message #4 prior to messages #2 & 3? The return value is waiting for the completion of the promise so the flow of the code and how the promise works is confusing me. Does the promise only hold up sending the return from the parent function while everything else continues to execute? or should the promise act like a pause until it's either resolved or rejected?

Comment: @BrianT it should not show 4 prior to 2/3. I added a runnable snippet - perhaps your code has something different happening. The promise will essentially pause and wait for a resolve/reject before continuing.

Comment: What you show is what I was expected but not what I'm seeing. I added the calling code and console output to my solution. See anything that could cause the out-of-order log?

Comment: @BrianT - it's because you are not resolving the promise. In my first solution I did mistakenly leave the `console.log('4--  leagueId: '+leagueId);` part instead of just returning the promise to be resolved. I've edited now to match the runnable sample - add `await` before `new Promise`

Comment: Thanks. I edited my final solution as well to add the await.

Answer (score 0):

May you should try this:
`async function getLeagueFromDraftPick(pickId) {`
`return new Promise((resolve, reject ) =>{`
  `pickId = Number(pickId);`
 `var leagueId;`
`console.log('1 pickId: '+pickId);`
  `if (pickId  <= 0) {`
`reject(false) ;`
`}`

`// Get LeagueID from draft based on pickId`
`// *** Need to "await" this query "`
  `connection.query('select LEAGUE_ID from DRAFT where ID=? limit 1',`
               `[pickId],`
                 `function (error, results, fields) {`
  `if (error) {`
      `reject(error ) ;`
  `} else {`
     `leagueId = results[0].LEAGUE_ID;`

```
  `resolve(leagueId) ;`
`}`
```

`});`
 `console.log('4--  leagueId: '+leagueId);`
`resolve(leagueId);`
`})`
`}`

Comment: Don't forget to have a path for errors , here you can use promise rejection. e.g.
```
reject(error);

```